# Use rspec let with array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a function `func` that returns an array with two arguments which I normally use as follows:

```
heads, tails = func
```

so in an rspec test, I would like to write

```
let(:heads, :tails, :draw){ func }
```

but this raises an exception. I know I can just put

```
let(:ans){ func }
let(:heads){ ans.first }
let(:tails){ ans.second }
```

Is there an easier way to do this in rspec. If not, is there a method call that I can write that do this for me e.g.

```
def let_multi(f)
    let(:ans){ f }
    let(:heads){ ans.first }
    let(:tails){ ans.second }
end
```

and then in the test

```
let_multi func
```

My attempt with `let_multi func` does not work because `func` is only defined in an `it` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing can't be done. Let blocks are evaluated outside of the `it` block context and need to be setup prior to that.

Even the rspec error output suggests as much when you try to dynamically define the `let`:

> `let` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).

This is because `let` blocks actually [define a method](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/f4dc5ef5c6bded2b1ec348e856352b60a3e072e9/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb#L284-L300) that match the symbol given to the `let`, which is then lazily evaluated. As such it would need to be a new feature of rspec to allow for this type of array based initialization.